# pyspark matrix with dummy variables

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Have two columns:

```
ID  Text
1    a
2    b
3    c
```

How can I able to create matrix with dummy variables like this:

```
ID a b c
1  1 0 0
2  0 1 0
3  0 0 1
```

Using pyspark library and its features?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c"),
], ["ID", "Text"])

categories = df.select("Text").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

exprs = [F.when(F.col("Text") == category, 1).otherwise(0).alias(category)
         for category in categories]

df.select("ID", *exprs).show()
```

Output

```
+---+---+---+---+
| ID|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  2|  0|  1|  0|
|  3|  0|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'F' is not defined

Comment: What is F here?

Comment: from pyspark.sql import functions as F

Comment: Thank you for this -- how would one combine the final select statement, "df.select("ID", *exprs).show()" with a list of columns rather than a single string reference to a column?

For example, if I wanted to do "df.select(df.columns, *exprs).show()" I would get the error message:

Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['column names...'] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function... can someone point me in the right direction?  Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

An alternative solution is to use Spark’s [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) method, which has been around since Spark 1.6.0.

Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c"),],
    ["ID", "Text"])    

pivoted = df.groupBy("ID").pivot("Text").agg(F.lit(1))
pivoted.show()
# +---+----+----+----+
# | ID|   a|   b|   c|
# +---+----+----+----+
# |  1|   1|null|null|
# |  3|null|null|   1|
# |  2|null|   1|null|
# +---+----+----+----+
```

To get rid of the missing values, simply use the `na` methods:

```
pivoted.na.fill(0).show()
# +---+---+---+---+
# | ID|  a|  b|  c|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1|  1|  0|  0|
# |  3|  0|  0|  1|
# |  2|  0|  1|  0|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

Pivoting is more general than the [solution proposed by ksindi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36946609/2476444), as it can aggregate numbers. That being said, the solution proposed by ksindi is more efficient in this particular case as it only requires one pass over the data, two if you take into account the pass to get the categories. For pivoting, you can also add the categories as the second positional parameter to `pivot` which improves efficiency. But the `groupBy` call will already cause a shuffle which makes this approach slower.

Note: the `groupBy` call silently assumes that the `ID` column in the example contains unique values to get to the desired output. Had the example dataframe looked like:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c"),
    (3, "a")],
    ["ID", "Text"])
```

the outcome of this solution would've been

```
df.groupBy("ID").pivot("Text").agg(F.lit(1)).na.fill(0).show()
# +---+---+---+---+
# | ID|  a|  b|  c|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1|  1|  0|  0|
# |  3|  1|  0|  1|
# |  2|  0|  1|  0|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

Whereas the mapping solution would end up as

```
df.select("ID", *exprs).show()
# +---+---+---+---+
# | ID|  c|  b|  a|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1|  0|  0|  1|
# |  2|  0|  1|  0|
# |  3|  1|  0|  0|
# |  3|  0|  0|  1|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: This approach is more clean to me, but one would also like to report the original column name in making the dummy columns, for example columns "a", "b", "c" should become `"Text_a", "Text_b", "Text_c"`. If for example you need to create dummy encodings from more than  one column you could unintentionally replace old columns. Plus you should indicate that a `F.monotonically_increasing_id` would help in distinguishing rows, acting as the `.groupBy` expression.

Answer (score 0):

If the dummy variables are for modeling, you can use the OneHotEncoder /OneHotEncoderEstimator (depending on version of pyspark).

An example can be shown in the [Spark MLlib Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#onehotencoder-deprecated-since-230).

Note that if you need to drop a column to prevent linear dependency (as is the case with regression) you should use `dropLast=True`.