# Creating dummy variables in sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, plyr, sparklyr

I'm trying to scale up some of my ML pipelines and i love the combination of rstudio, spark, and h2o that sparklyr opens up (http://spark.rstudio.com/)

One thing i'm trying to figure out is how to use sparklyr to create dummy cols from a character vector in a data frame.

I've tried the below but i think it might be mixing some functions that sparklyr has not yet implemented.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

flights_tbl <- copy_to(sc, nycflights13::flights, "flights")

flights_tbl %>% bind_cols(as_data_frame(setNames(lapply(unique(flights_tbl$carrier), 
                                               function(x){as.integer(flights_tbl$carrier == x)}), 
                                        paste0('var2_', levels(flights_tbl$carrier)))))
```

In this example i'd like to create indicator variables for each carrier.

To be honest i'm not really familiar with dplyr so not sure how i'd do this.

Is there maybe a spark function that already exits that i might be able to call via a sparklyr extension or is there a way to do this with just dplyr functions?

**Update**

I think i have a way to do this in pyspark on a dataframe (in case useful for anyone).

So if data looks like:

```
>>> df.show(20)
+------------+----------+------+-----------+
|        word|word_count|corpus|corpus_date|
+------------+----------+------+-----------+
|  profession|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|      augury|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|undertakings|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|     surmise|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|    religion|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|    advanced|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|    Wormwood|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|   parchment|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|     villany|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|        digs|         1|hamlet|       1600|
| authorities|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|      Popp'd|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|  retrograde|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|       tax'd|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|        tomb|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|       moral|         1|hamlet|       1600|
| foreknowing|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|  dreadfully|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|      parted|         1|hamlet|       1600|
|      willow|         1|hamlet|       1600|
+------------+----------+------+-----------+
```

Then the following seems to work for making dummies on the [word] field:

```
categories = df.select("word").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

exprs = [F.when(F.col("word") == category, 1).otherwise(0).alias(category) for category in categories]

df_dummies = df.select("word", *exprs).limit(1000)
```

taken from ([pyspark matrix with dummy variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879372/pyspark-matrix-with-dummy-variables))

Answer (score 2):

These may be new since the original post. The `ml_` functions has [ml_create_dummy_variables](http://spark.rstudio.com/reference/ml_create_dummy_variables.html) which does the job nicely

```
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)

iris_dum <- ml_create_dummy_variables(iris_tbl, "Species")

iris_dum %>% select(contains("Species")) %>% head

> 
Source:   query [6 x 4]
Database: spark connection master=local[4] app=lol local=TRUE

  Species Species_setosa Species_versicolor Species_virginica
    <chr>          <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>
1  setosa              1                  0                 0
2  setosa              1                  0                 0
3  setosa              1                  0                 0
4  setosa              1                  0                 0
5  setosa              1                  0                 0
6  setosa              1                  0                 0
```

Shame they're `<dbl>` and not `<int>` but that's easily fixed with an `as.integer` call.

Comment: This is useful when converting a single column, but are there any simple solutions when converting multiple factor columns?

Comment: Not totally sure. Version 0.7 has since come out, which adds a lot of the pipeline functionality from SparkML. Perhaps there's something new there (not investigated).

Comment: It looks like `ml_create_dummy_variables` has been quietly deprecated in 0.7. `ft_one_hot_encoder` is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with sparklyr, but creating dummy features for categorical variables is indeed implemented in Spark.

Spark's [One Hot Encoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) takes in a column of $n$ integer indices and creates $n-1$ corresponding dummy columns. If your data is still in String/Factor form in R, you might have to convert it to indices first using Spark's StringIndexer (see link above).

Comment: cool thanks - have always wondered about this - how do you keep track of what integer refers to what original string? Sort sort of dictionary?

Comment: I believe Spark indices the Strings by frequency, i.e. the most frequent item will have index 0. In any case, Spark also has an [IndexToString](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IndexToString) class that can reverse the indexing.