# Split lists in a column into one hot encoded features in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like the following:

| id | tmp_list | other features |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ['Spain', 'Italy'] | xxx |
| 2 | ['Spain', 'France', 'USA', 'India'] | yyy |
| 3 | ['Spain', 'Germany'] | zzz |

and a list of countries like the following:

`EU_countries = ['Spain', 'Italy', 'France', 'Germany']`

I want to do the following:

1. Extract all unique values from the column `tmp_list`
2. Create new columns for all the values present in `EU_countries`. For the values that don't exist in `EU_countries`, create a column called `other_countries`. Essentially, create column for every entry in `EU_countries` list + an extra column called `other_countries`.
3. If an `id` contains any of the countries from the `EU_countries` list, the new column `Spain` should have `1` as value else `0`. Same applies to the other countries from `EU_countries` list.
4. If an `id` contains any country that doesn't exist in the `EU_countries` list, `other_countries` column should be filled `1` else `0`.

This is the final output I am looking for:

| id | Spain | Italy | France | Germany | other_countries | other features |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | xxx |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | yyy |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | zzz |

I am breaking my head over this. Can somebody please help me with this?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: try onehotencoder from pyspark ml?

Comment: I think it creates different combinations of the list. By that, I mean, `spain, italy` would be one column, `spain,france,USA, india` would be another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: replace all non-EU countries in `tmp_list` with a constant string:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = ...
EU_countries = ['Spain', 'Italy', 'France', 'Germany']

def replaceNonEU(c):
    cond = c == EU_countries[0]
    for country in EU_countries[1:]:
        cond |= (c == country)
    return F.when(cond, c).otherwise(F.lit("other_countries"))

df = df.withColumn("tmp_list", F.array_distinct(F.transform("tmp_list", replaceNonEU)))

#+---+--------------------------------+--------------+
#|id |tmp_list                        |other features|
#+---+--------------------------------+--------------+
#|1  |[Spain, Italy]                  |xxx           |
#|2  |[Spain, France, other_countries]|yyy           |
#|3  |[Spain, Germany]                |zzz           |
#+---+--------------------------------+--------------+
```

**Step 2**: for each possible value in `tmp_list` create a new column indicating if the value is an element of `tmp_list`:

```python
for c in EU_countries + ['other_countries']:
    df = df.withColumn(c, F.array_contains("tmp_list", c).cast("int"))
df = df.drop("tmp_list")

#+---+--------------+-----+-----+------+-------+---------------+
#| id|other features|Spain|Italy|France|Germany|other_countries|
#+---+--------------+-----+-----+------+-------+---------------+
#|  1|           xxx|    1|    1|     0|      0|              0|
#|  2|           yyy|    1|    0|     1|      0|              1|
#|  3|           zzz|    1|    0|     0|      1|              0|
#+---+--------------+-----+-----+------+-------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Reasoning and working like I would in pandas.

1. Explode
2. Create Category where non EU_countries are attributed as other_countries
3. get_dummies. On this one I give credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879372/pyspark-matrix-with-dummy-variables)

Code below;

```
df=df.select('*').withColumn('tmp_list1', F.explode(col('tmp_list')))#Create new column with exploded list
df=df.select('*').withColumn('Cat', when(col('tmp_list1').isin(EU_countries),df.tmp_list1).otherwise('other_countries'))#Create another column Cat
df.groupBy("tmp_list",'other features').pivot("Cat").agg(F.lit(1)).na.fill(0).show()#Get dummies


+---------------------------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+---------------+
|tmp_list                   |other features|France|Germany|Italy|Spain|other_countries|
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+---------------+
|[Spain, Germany]           |zzz           |0     |1      |0    |1    |0              |
|[Spain, Italy]             |xxx           |0     |0      |1    |1    |0              |
|[Spain, France, USA, India]|yyy           |1     |0      |0    |1    |1              |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-------+-----+-----+---------------+
```

Comment: depending on the size of the data, exploding + re-grouping might cause a lot of shuffling